# React parent couldn't update a child component in a mapped JSX list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

NOTE: You can view and edit the code in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-hertz-rcbtms?file=/src/App.js).

I have the following parent file which creates a `useState` list of child component called `ProgressBar`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';
import './App.css';

var idCounter = 0;

export default function App() {
  const [barsArray, setBarsArray] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  function add() {
    setBarsArray((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      <ProgressBar key={idCounter++} restart={false} />,
    ]);
  }

  function remove() {
    setBarsArray((prev) => prev.filter((bar) => bar.key !== input));
  }

  function reset() {
    setBarsArray((prev) =>
      prev.map((bar) => (bar.key === input ? { ...bar, restart: true } : bar))
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='buttons'>
        <button className='button-add' onClick={add}>
          Add
        </button>
        <button className='button-delete' onClick={remove}>
          Delete
        </button>
        <button className='button-delete' onClick={reset}>
          Reset
        </button>
        <input
          type='number'
          value={input}
          onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='bars-container'>
        {barsArray.map((bar) => (
          <div className='bars-index' key={bar.key}>
            {bar}
            <p>{bar.key}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The file of the child `ProgressBar` has the following content:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './ProgressBar.css';

export default function ProgressBar(props) {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  let interval;

  useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, RnadInt(10, 120));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (progress >= 100) clearInterval(interval);
  }, [progress]);

  if (props.restart === true) {
    setProgress(0);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className='ProgressBarContainer'>
        <div className='ProgressBar' style={{ width: progress + '%' }}></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function RnadInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

My problem is that the reset button in the parent doesn't work, as far as I'm concerned, if you change the passed props to the child, the child automatically re-renders, but even though I'm updating the props in `reset` function in the parent, which maps the old array of child components to a new array and only changes the props of the selected child.

Thanks!

Comment: you are reseting right? so you can set the state to empty array right?

Comment: Instead of adding `<ProgressBar` at `add()` metthod and looping over it, use the model object and bind to component at render using `<ProgressBar {...bar}  />`

Comment: @Aravind Yes I'm resetting, but I can't access the children's state from the parent, that's why I can't pass any state at all.

Comment: @user1672994 Could you please reformat the `add()` function to help me understand the syntax of doing so? Thanks.

Comment: Check the forked codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-glitter-j3b7sw?file=/src/App.js:250-346

Comment: It worked! thank you.
To help anyone having similar problem I'd like you to post your answer so I can select it as the best answer.

Comment: @Balawi28 - posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the element in state via `add` would require to keep the ref of element instead of actual prop bind to element. Suggestion here to use the model object and while rendering use the JSX element.

Please use the below code which defines the `barsArray` as object state and later uses it render `ProgressBar` component (from map call).

Check the working codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-glitter-j3b7sw?file=/src/App.js:0-1446

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ProgressBar from "./ProgressBar";
import "./App.css";

var idCounter = 0;

export default function App() {
  const [barsArray, setBarsArray] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  function add() {
    setBarsArray((prev) => [...prev, { id: idCounter++, restart: false }]);
  }

  function remove() {
    setBarsArray((prev) =>
      prev.filter((bar) => bar.id.toString() !== input.toString())
    );
  }

  function reset() {
    setBarsArray((prev) =>
      prev.map((bar) => {
        return bar.id.toString() === input.toString()
          ? { ...bar, restart: true }
          : { ...bar };
      })
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="buttons">
        <button className="button-add" onClick={add}>
          Add
        </button>
        <button className="button-delete" onClick={remove}>
          Delete
        </button>
        <button className="button-delete" onClick={reset}>
          Reset
        </button>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={input}
          onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="bars-container">
        {barsArray.map((bar) => (
          <div className="bars-index" key={bar.id}>
            <ProgressBar key={bar.id} restart={bar.restart} />
            <p>{bar.key}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```